# Exit codes in if statement is different to exit codes standalone

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "1"=="1" CALL :ADDHOST & echo 1:[%ERRORLEVEL%]
CALL :ADDHOST & echo 2:[%ERRORLEVEL%]
PAUSE
EXIT

:ADDHOST
EXIT /B 3
```

Output:

```
[1]:0  
[2]:3  
Press any key to continue
```

How can I get the correct exit code  ( 3 ) when call something inside the if block?

Comment: Btw. The second line fails exactly like the first line, but you didn't see it, because the `errorlevel` is already `3`

Comment: Can you explain it in details @jeb I'm a dummy

Comment: The details are explained in [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected). In short: variables are expanded when a line or block is parsed, **before** it's executed. In your case the `%errorlevel%` expands before `CALL :ADDHOST` was executed.